# Como integrar OpenGL ao Netbeans e iniciar o desenvolvimento?

Tags: opengl

Quero integrar a "biblioteca" OpenGL ao IDE NetBeans 8.0.2(versão atual). Então, importa-la em uma classe no NetBeans(comando **import** ou outra forma) e iniciar o desenvolvimento.

Comment: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3260/netbeans-opengl-pack

Comment: O que exatamente acontece nesse processo? A falha está em executar algo feito em *OpenGL* no *Netbeans* ou em conseguir iniciar o desenvolvimento no *Netbeans*?